# LINQ to XML set value if it is not null otherwise use default value from the constructor

Tags: c#, xml, linq, linq-to-xml

I need to read an XML file and I am using LINQ to XML approach. When creating instances of the `Ignore` class there is a problem, because `mode` and `pattern` attributes do not have to be in the XML if they should be set to a default value which is defined in a constructor of the `Ignore` class.

The code below works, but only if all attributes are present in the XML file.

```
var items = xmlFile.Descendants("item")
                   .Select(x => new Item()
                       {
                           SourcePath = x.Attribute("source").ToString(),
                           DestinationPath = x.Attribute("destination").ToString(),
                           IgnoredSubitems = new List<Ignore>(
                              x.Elements("ignore")
                               .Select(y => new Ignore(
                                   path: y.Value,
                                   mode: GetEnumValue<IgnoreMode>(y.Attribute("mode")),
                                   pattern: GetEnumValue<IgnorePattern>(y.Attribute("style"))
                                ))
                            )
                        })
                    .ToList();
```

`GetEnumValue` method used to set enum types looks like the following

```
private static T GetEnumValue<T>(XAttribute attribute)
{
    return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), attribute.ToString());
}
```

Is there a way how to set the fields only if there are values, otherwise use default values defined in the constructor? The `Ignore` class **should be immutable** therefore I can't first instantiate it with default values and then try to assign values to properties, which provides only getters.

**EDIT:**

Based on misunderstood answers.
The `Ignore` class looks like the following. Please, note that it is not my class.

```
public class Ignore
{
    string Path { get; }
    IgnoreMode Mode { get; } // enum
    IgnorePattern Pattern { get; } // enum

    public Ignore(string path, IgnoreMode mode = someDefaultValue, IgnorePattern pattern = someDefaultPattern) 
    { 
        ... I don't know what happens here, but I guess that arguments are assigned to the properties ... 
    }
}
```

The default values can change over time, I can't hardcode them in my loader.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you may use some reflection like this

```
var constructor = typeof(Ignore).GetConstructor(new Type[]{typeof(string),typeof(IgnoreMode),typeof(IgnorePattern)});
var parameters = constructor.GetParameters(); // this return list parameters of selected constructor
var defaultIgnoreMode = (IgnoreMode)parameters[1].DefaultValue;
var defaultIgnorePattern = (IgnorePattern)parameters[2].DefaultValue;
```

Comment: Yes, I could do that.

Answer (score 0):

pass string parameter to your GetEnumValue method

```
var items = xmlFile.Descendants("item")
                   .Select(x => new Item()
                       {
                           SourcePath = x.Attribute("source").ToString(),
                           DestinationPath = x.Attribute("destination").ToString(),
                           IgnoredSubitems = new List<Ignore>(
                              x.Elements("ignore")
                               .Select(y => new Ignore(
                                   path: y.Value,
                                   mode: GetEnumValue<IgnoreMode>((string)y.Attribute("mode")),
                                   pattern: GetEnumValue<IgnorePattern>((string)y.Attribute("style"))
                                ))
                            )
                        })
                    .ToList();
```

Now change your method like this

```
private static T GetEnumValue<T>(string attribute)
{
    if(attribute==null) return YOURDEFAULTVALUE;
    else return (T)Enum.Parse(typeof(T), attribute);
}
```

hope it will work for you

Comment: It won't work for me. See, I don't know the default values, I can't specify them. Default valus are defined in the Ignore class and I am not the author of the class. I got it as it is.